# objective C: problem with open a second time a subview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, subview

I have this code to open a subview

```
- (IBAction) showList:(id) sender {

if( list == nil){

    list = [[ListClient alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListClient" bundle:nil];
    [list setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:list.view];
}
}
```

and this code to close this subview

```
-(IBAction) closeListClient {
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

}

it's ok for the first time, but at second time when i want to open the subview, it don't work, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `list` is not `nil` so it doesn't go inside `if (list == nil)`.

Change it to `if (list.superview == nil)`.

Comment: Although this will work, it will leak a `ListClient` object every time `showList` is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction) closeListClient{
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
if ( list != nil ) {
    [list release];
    list=nil;
}}
```

Comment: Although this will work, it will leak a `ListClient` object every time it's dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `if` statement. Change it to:

```
if ( list == nil ) {
    list = [[ListClient alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListClient" bundle:nil];
    [list setDelegate:self];
}
[self.view addSubview:list.view];
```

And it will work.

**PS.** To fix the memory management of this, add a retained property `list` to the class so you can say

```
self.list = [[[ListClient alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListClient" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

And you can say `self.list = nil;` to release the object when you're done with it. (eg while dismissing or in your `dealloc` method)